How to find the legs of a right triangle if its hypotenuse is numerically equal to its area?
I have an amazing ancient problem collection book by Chistyakov. I have managed to solve 165 problems of 248 (as of now, i. e. of time of current question posting); the remaining ones are really hard.
If you permit, I would like to ask help for problem #100.
One must find the legs (= catheti) of a right triangle, if it is known that its hypotenuse is numerically equal to its area.
So hypotenuse equals area (ignoring the units of measurement). Find the catheti!
[I suppose if there are multiple such triangles, then we must find all of them or find a general formula or something like that.]
How to solve such kind of geometrical problem?

What is the name of the book? Can you tell me as well?

Let the cateti be $a$ and $b$, the hypotenuse $c$, and the area $A$.  You are told $c = A$.  Now, isn't there a formula for $A$ that connects it to $a$ and $b$?  And isn't there a famous theorem that connects $a$, $b$ and $c$?  If you find those, you got yourself a system of equations...

It's worth noting that since you're (numerically) equating an area with a length, scaling any right-angled triangle appropriately will give you a solution. If your initial triangle has hypotenuse $c$ and legs $a,b$, the ratio of the hypotenuse to the area is $\frac{2c}{ab}$. If the scaled triangle has corresponding sides $at,bt,ct$, the ratio becomes $\frac{2c}{abt}$; so choosing $t=\frac{2c}{ab}$ will give you a solution.

The right angle of the triangle lies on a circle whose diameter is the hypotenuse.
In order for the area to equal the hypotenuse, the altitude on the hypotenuse is $2$.
These two facts exactly determine the shape of the triangle.

Let the length of the hypotenuse be $c = AB$ in the figure.
Then $OC = \frac c2$. Let $h = CM$; then the area of triangle $\triangle ABC$ is
$\frac12 hc = c$ and therefore $h = 2$.
By the Pythagorean Theorem on triangle $\triangle CMO$,
then $(MO)^2 = (OC)^2 - (CM)^2 = \frac{c^2}{4} - 4$.
Then
\begin{align}
(AC)^2
&= (AM)^2 + (CM)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac c2 - \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} - 4}\right)^2 + 4 \\
&= \frac{c^2}2 - c\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} - 4} \\
&= \frac c2\left(c - \sqrt{c^2 - 16}\right), \\
(BC)^2
&= (BM)^2 + (CM)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac c2 + \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} - 4}\right)^2 + 4 \\
&= \frac{c^2}2 + c\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4} - 4} \\
&= \frac c2\left(c + \sqrt{c^2 - 16}\right). \\
\end{align}

Let $ACB$ be a triangle right angled at $C$ let $AB=c, AC= b, BC = a$. Then by Pythagoras theorem $a^2+b^2=c^2$ but given $c=\frac{ab}{2}$. Plugging in and simplifying you get $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}=\frac{1}{4} $ 
Now using reciprocal Pythagoras theorem the lhs is equal to $\frac{1}{d^2}$ where $d$ is the altitude from the side $AB$ to the vertex $C$ solving you get $d=2$.

Now draw this altitude and using trigonometry find that $b=\frac{2}{\cos (A)}$ and $a=\frac{2}{\sin (A)}$

Ahh yes thank you, I edited it now.

It should be $sin(α)$ and $cos(α)$, not $sin(A)$ and $cos(A)$.

In the triangle $ABC$ right angled at $C$, call $F$ the foot of the perpendicular from the vertex $C$ on the hypotenuse. Denote the lengths of the mentionned segments $c,a,b,h$ respectivelly.
The use of the "area=hypotenuse" constraint
$$c=\frac{hc}{2}=\frac{ab}{2}$$
gives $$h=2\quad\text{and}\quad ab=2c.$$
There exist infinity of convenient triangles. The minimal area is $4,$ the triangle is then isosceles. There is no bound for the area maximum.
For the construction, I used Euclid altitude theorem, as it is called in my country. The corresponding identity
$$|AF|\cdot |FB|=h^2$$ is due to similar right triangles $AFC$ and $CFB.$


[
TO FIND THE LEGS OF THE RIGHT TRIANGLE HAVING ITS HYPOTENUSE AS IT'S AREA
Consider ABC a triangle such that AC is the hypotenuse while AB (b) and BC (a) will be the sides (legs).
Now , $ AC = \frac{1}{2} ab $
$ BC = AC \cosθ $
$ a = 1 / 2 ab \cosθ $
$ b = 2 / \cos θ $
Similarly $ AB = AC \sinθ $
$ b = 1 / 2 ab \sinθ $
$ a = 2 / \sinθ $
Therefore , $ b = 2 \secθ $
$ a = 2 \operatorname{cosec}θ $
